# Components of blackColor() and whiteColor()

Tags: ios, uicolor

Some built-in colors really confused me:

```
let color = UIColor.blackColor()
let colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)
let red = colorComponents[0]
let green = colorComponents[1]
let blue = colorComponents[2]
let alpha = colorComponents[3]
print("red: \(red)\ngreen: \(green)\nblue: \(blue)\nalpha: \(alpha)")
```

I get

> red: 0.0
>   green: 1.0
>   blue: 2.41104035170528e-321
>   alpha: 4.94065645841247e-324

Shouldn't it be **red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1**?

When I use `whiteColor()`, I get

> red: 1.0
>   green: 1.0
>   blue: 2.184138553679e-314
>   alpha: 2.19371200885718e-314

Shouldn't it be **red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1**?

I use Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2

Comment: Why are you assuming those colors are RGBA colors?

Comment: Why are you still using Swift 2 and Xcode 7?

Comment: @rmaddy Even those colors may not be RGBA colors, but in my opinion they can be expressed by RGBA values. The link you provide is helpful, tks.